# How to disable button in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Onclick of button,(In clientclick event)I show confrmation box having ok and cancel button.Onclick of ok button,buttonclick event fire.I want to disable button and show to message(Pls wait) to user.I am trying but not working.Unable to disable the button and set text to label.

```
function validate()
{
  var response = confirm(Proceed)
  if(response)
  {
     document.getElementById('btnSave').disabled = true;
     document.getElementById('lblMessage').innerText = 'Please Wait';
     return true;
  }
  else
  {
        return false;
  }

}
```

I am getting error.Error is
JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'innerText' of undefined or null reference in asp.net

Comment: Add `ClientIDMode = "static"` attribute to `btnSave` and `lblMessage` and try

Comment: Why clientmode = static?

Comment: `ASP.Net` controls will render to native html elements. While rendering, `asp.net` will alter the `ID` and set the `ID` based on content hierarchy. So you may not get exact ID as you mentioned in `ASP.Net` code. By using `ClientIDMore = "static"` ID won't change while rendering.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there's maybe a problem in your HTML. Javascript cannot find the 'lblMessage' element. Fix that first and you're good to go.

Maybe you're using ASP.NET Web Forms. ASP.NET changes the client ID's of server controls depending on the ID of their container. You can change this behavior easily by reading this article:

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40

Or, find your elements by class name. That way it won't cause conflict with any configuration you're now using.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add your html code. I'm guessing your html looks like this

```
<button onclick="validate()">
```

you need to add a return statement into the html code so it looks like this

```
<button onclick="return validate()">
```